# connect but no internet

Tags: wireless

I am returning user at ubuntu, and i can not come online or use software center, and the wireless say connected, and i try enter in the terminal:

```
    rfkill list
```

and it say no soft block and no hard block, and i try enter in terminal:

```
    lspci
```

and say (atholen wireless on pci), and i try enter in the terminal:

```
    lsmod wlan0
```

and say lsmod: users, and since I can not use nmap to scan hosts if it is up when nmap is not install, and i tried making a script called network.d i enter:

#bin/sh

```
    case ![$] in
        ./bin/sh
        nmcli nm -c asleep=false -network
    easc
```

and still not online, can some one please help me come back online.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>